# Calculate potential between two rods

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, electric-field

Suppose we got four thin, long and parallell conductors with charges shown in the image below. Each conductor has a radius \$ r\$  and length \$ l\$ . Our problem is to find the potential between the outer most conductors:

[image]

---

**My attempt:** First and foremost we know that the electric field from a conductor can be expressed as:

$$  \vec{E} = \frac{\rho_l}{2\pi\varepsilon_0 R} \hat{r} $$

This formula is taken from page 89 in the 2nd edition of *Field and Wave Electromagnetics* by *David K. Cheng*. Notice that \$\rho_l\$ is the line charge density and \$R\$ is the radial distance.

I thought that I now can calculate the total electric field with respect to the first rod using superposition of the formula above, and then integrate from the outer most left rod to the outer most right rod using the formula:

$$ V_2 - V_1 = -\int_{1}^{2} \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dl}$$

Where the integration bounds instead would be from  \$r \$ to  \$3a-r \$. However I don't know whether this is the correct procedure. Can anyone give me any feedback or tips on my method?

Comment: I think there's an option to ask this on physics SE but, you'll probably want to not cross-post questions because it is frowned upon.

Comment: Without any information about the relative nature of length \$l\$, radius \$r\$, and separation \$a\$, finding useful symmetries is 'more difficult'. Worse, these are rods! This means ***sharp*** rims at each end. Which is where the charges will be closer together and the E-field will concentrate itself. And are you supposed to compute the lines of equipotential in 3D space? Or what simplifications are you allowed? Too little information for me to offer help.

Comment: @periblepsis I'm sorry but that's all the information I've got to solve the problem.

Comment: @Tanamas Then I'll leave it where it lays.